# Passing dates to parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

In which format I should pass date field to parameter to be able to choose date picker insted of list?

My query returns date (date format) and I cast it in a different ways (yyyy-dd-MM, yyyy-MM-dd, dd-MM-yyyy, ...) in SSRS:

```
=Format(Fields!StartDate2.Value,"yyyy-dd-MM")
```

I use this field in parameter, but I always get error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   The property ‘ValidValues’ of report parameter ‘STARTDATE’ doesn't
>   have the expected type. (rsParameterPropertyTypeMismatch)

When I just passing result of query (date format), I have list:

[image]

even If chose Date/Time:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Answer**

The reason you are getting this problem is because the Language/Culture/Date Format on your environments are not similar.

SQL by DEFAULT uses en-US and your local pc uses your local Language/Culture/Date Format.

there is your problem, instead of converting the value of your dates to your local
Language/Culture/Date Format, convert it to en-US 
"MM-dd-yyyy"

**Answer explained**

to put this in perspective you are sending a SQL server with the date format 
"MM/dd/yyyy" the value "2017/16/03".

so the server thinks "this guy is telling me to search for the 2017th month, 16th day of the year 03"

Comment: is struggled with this one about 2-3 months ago aswell :)

Comment: I've changed expression to =Format(Fields!StartDate2.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy"), but I still get this error.

Comment: Go on your SSRS SQL server, check its language....the goal is for your reports to send SSRS the dates in the same format as the language of the SSRS sql server

Comment: if the problem appears INSIDE SSRS itself, you need to check the language of the server that contains all your data..they might be out of sync :)

Comment: My language is English (United States).

Comment: @Testtest11 on both SQL servers ?

Comment: @Testtest11 Also in your report creator, under localisation(properties) set the language of the report to "=User!Language" and remove the =Format(Fields!StartDate2.Value,"yyyy-dd-MM")

Comment: English (United States) on database engine (server) but I open report in my local computer in browser.